# Нужно ли очищать setInterval если он находится в setTimeout который очистил? И если нужно, то как?

Tags: javascript

В принципе вся суть вопроса в самом вопросе, вот пример кода:

```js
const framesImg = () => {

        timerOne = setTimeout(() => {
            productListItemTextProgressGradOne.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
            itemNum5.classList.remove('active');
            itemNum1.classList.add('active');
            productImg5.classList.remove('active');
            productImg1.classList.add('active');
            
            intervalOne = setInterval(() => {
                productListItemTextProgressGradOne.style.animation = 'product_progress linear 25s infinite'
                itemNum5.classList.remove('active');
                itemNum1.classList.add('active');
                productImg5.classList.remove('active');
                productImg1.classList.add('active');
            }, 25000);
            
        }, 5000); 
        
    }

    framesImg();


    itemNum.forEach(elem => {
        elem.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
           clearTimeout(timerOne);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Вы и ответьте, нужно вам его удалять или нет? А по поводу как это сделать, в вашем примере никак, так как нет к нему доступа извне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) и [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) никак не связаны между собой, поэтому, для остановки интервала нужно его остановить с помощью метода [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval).

При этом, очевидно, что интервал не запустится, если событие `mouseover` произойдет раньше чем выполнится callback `setTimeout`. В этом случае, дополнительно вызывать [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) не надо.

Но, так как [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) не бросает исключения, если пришел некорректный параметр можно просто всегда вызывать его:

```
clearTimeout(timerOne);
clearInterval(intervalOne);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что я хотел узнать. А можно ли еще узнать, запустился ли уже setTimeout или нет? Допустим прошло уже 4 секунды, а таймаут должен сработать через 5 секунд, но я не уверен , может уже и 6 секунд прошло и я бы хотел при наводе на блок, узнать, он уже сработал или еще нет (допустим в консоле вывести true или false)

Comment: @Павел, если сработал setTimeout - выполнился его callback, соответственно добавились все классы, который ты добавляешь и установилось значение переменной intervalOne

Comment: Не совсем то. У меня есть несколько setTimeout, один срабатывает через 5000, второй через 10000 и третий через 15000. В каждом setTimeout есть setInterval. И мне нужно очищать это все в разное время, и иногда какой-то setTimeout не успевает сработать. А когда хочу очистить setInterval, то получается он еще не создан и выдает ошибку. Вот как можно узнать сработал ли setTimeout не опираясь на это " соответственно добавились все классы"

Comment: @Павел "то получается он еще не создан" - объявите переменную, чтобы она существовала до присвоения ей значения.

Comment: @Павел, _А когда хочу очистить setInterval, то получается он еще не создан и выдает ошибку._ - ты получаешь ошибку не потому, что setInterval еще не создан.